# how to put controller in external files

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I am having problem on getting controllers to work when they are outside of my app config file. When I put class testCtrl (with little modification - removing module, export and static field) into file with configuration It works properly.

This is my external controller file ctrl.ts:

```
module routing.Controllers
{ 
export class testCtrl
{ 
    static $inject = ["$scope"];

    constructor($scope : any)
    { 
        $scope.events  = this;
    }

    showAlert()
    {
        alert('Clicked');
    }    
} 
}
```

And this is my file with configuration routing.ts:

```
declare var angular: any;

var app = angular.module("routing", ['ngRoute']); 

app.controller('Test', routing.Controllers.testCtrl);

app.config(($routeProvider) => {
  $routeProvider
    .when('/index',{ templateUrl: 'views/LogIn.html',controller:'Test' })
    .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/index' });
})
```

In editor in app.controller line the routing is underlined as error and it says:

> Could not find 'routing'

And in browser I get error saying:

> ReferenceError: routing is not defined

Am I doing something wrong?

PS: I work under eclipse no idea if It matters.

Answer (score 0):

> Am I doing something wrong?

If you do not have an `export` keyword at the *root* level of your file it implies that you want to use `--out` or `script` tags.

> ReferenceError: routing is not defined

This is a common frustration : https://github.com/TypeStrong/atom-typescript/blob/master/docs/out.md#runtime-errors

> In editor in app.controller line the routing is underlined as error and it say

This is because your IDE does not support simple *compilation context* support. A quick fix would be to add a `reference` tag. A better fix is to use a `tsconfig.json` file : https://github.com/TypeStrong/atom-typescript/blob/master/docs/tsconfig.md

## Solution

Use file based modules : http://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/project/modules.html

Along with a runtime like require js. You will need to compile with `--module amd`

More : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KDrWLMUY0R0&hd=1

Comment: so if I would like to import class I should use  import {testCtrl} from "./controllers/ctrl"; (ctrl.ts is inside controllers folder) ? (it shows me that this file is not a module)